# Adding a BoundCoulmn to the ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagrid object. I am simply adding a BoundColumn to the aspx file and I am trying to access it in the backend (aspx.vb file).

So:

```
sql temp table:
PreExisting int,
New int 'I added this to a pre-existing SP

aspx file
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="PreExisting"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="New"></asp:BoundColumn> 'want to use this instead

aspx.vb file
Dim Test as new BoundColumn      'want to remove
Test.DataField = "New"           'want to remove
datagridobject.Columns.Add(Test) 'want to remove
For each item as DataGridItem in datagridobject.Items
    item.Cells(0).Text = "Works"
    item.Cells(1).Text = "Doesn't Work"
```

This is just a basic overview, but shouldn't editing the aspx add the column to the datagrid permanently? OR do I need to manually add a new column object in the aspx.vb EACH time the page is loaded?

EDIT:

I'm filling a DataSet with an SQL temp table with the columns"PreExisting" and "New". However, the current DataGrid will not find the "New" column after I bind the DataSet. I've tried adding a new BoundColumn with the Datafield = "New" in the aspx.vb file, which works, but I want to remove this chunk of code and simply add it to the aspx file. Is THIS possible, because I was told it was. If not I will simply keep the previous chunk that works. *

Comment: "shouldn't editing the aspx add the column to the datagrid permanently". Short answer, no, if you're adding things to the grid programatically like this you have to do it every time you bind the grid. They are assumed to be temporary (as if they were the result of one-off or variable calculations, for example) and not preserved in the ViewState or anything like that.

Comment: How would I go about adding it permanently to the pre-existing code? I'm working with SQL temp table data. I've added a new column to the temp table and I'm trying to manipulate it in VB, but I'd rather not have to create a new BoundColumn each time I bind the grid. If it's the only way (which I've confirmed works already) then that's fine

Comment: It looks like your vb code is setting the text of existing columns though, not adding new columns? A BoundColumn is normally bound to the datasource, so inevitably when you bind it, it will take its value from the data source again. Also those columns in the example are invisible. Are you making them visible somewhere else?

Comment: What I'm confused by is my current DataGrid has 15 columns in the pre-existing code, and the DataGrid is simply bound to the SQL DataSet, so I was assuming the BoundColumns in the aspx file would correspond to the .vb side of things. It looked like to me that this was done manually, but perhaps if I removed the new BoundCoulmn and tested again, maybe the new Column in my temp table will appear? Also, they are ID's that are being kept hidden for backend use

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by this. What temp table? What "vb side of things"? The VB side of things consists of whatever you decide to write. If you add a new column in the aspx, it will bind as long as it matches the field name in the DataTable properly. You need to set Visible="true" before it will show on the page though. It's not really clear how the VB part comes into it, as there's no context for how and where that code is executing, or whether the column IDs you're using correspond to the ones in your aspx sample.

Comment: just come back to this. Thanks for the clarification. Yes it should be possible to do what you're suggesting and put the declaration of the "New" column into the aspx instead of the VB. When you say it does not "find" the column what do you mean by this? It doesn't show up? You get some sort of error? As long as the data source contains the column it ought to work. Can you show us how you get the data from the database, and how you bind the data to the grid?

Comment: I fixed the issue, I added a OnItemDataBound sub to the grid tab on the ASPX page. The sub had access to all of my SQL data directly, so I didn't need to add a new column. In terms of why my previous solution wasn't working, that's still unknown. My colleague mentioned that what I was doing, modifying the ASPX page directly, should have worked, and that my datagrid object not finding the new boundcolumn was very odd. I was doing all of this in the BindGrid sub, so perhaps it was something to do with scope? Either way it works now, Thanks!